# Como atribuir um valor diferente a variável em cada loop?

Tags: php

```
$azul = "#4285f4"; // AZUL
$verde = "#34a853"; // VERDE
$amarelo = "#fbbc05"; // AMARELO
$vermelho = "#ea4335"; // VERMELHO
$color = rand(1, 4);
```

Estou usando `$color` dentro de um ***loop*** mas dessa forma tão simplória que está o meu código, o valor da variável citada pode se repetir tipo `3, 3, 1`.

Como fazer com que num espaço de `3 loops`, o valor não se repita formando sequências do tipo `1, 2, 3`, `1, 3, 2`, `3, 2, 1`, `3, 1, 2` etc ...

```
while ( $destaques->have_posts() ) { $destaques->the_post(); 

     if($color == 1) { $color = $azul; }
     elseif ($color == 2) { $color = $verde; }
     elseif ($color == 3) { $color = $amarelo; }
     elseif ($color == 4) { $color = $vermelho; } ?>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Acho que você pode mudar a sua abordagem para esse código.

Defina um array com as cores no lugar de variáveis individuais, com `shuffle()` embaralhe os valores, use o `echo` com `array_shift()` para exibir o valor atual do array e remove-lo, dessa forma a cor/valor não se repete.

```
<?php
$cores = ["#4285f4", "#34a853", "#fbbc05","#ea4335"];
shuffle($cores);

 $i = 0;
 while($i < 4){
    echo array_shift($cores) .'<br>';
    $i++;
 }
```

Comment: Estou com um problema sério em aprender `arrays` @rray ... Não dá aulas particulares pelo Skype, Teamviewer ou alguma coisa assim? Solução perfeita.

Comment: @MarcosVinicius, haha da pra conversar sobre o assunto se tiver interesse.

Answer (score 2):

Exemplo com uma rotação contínua

```
$arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4); //aqui seriam as 4 cores.
$data = range(1, 100); // isso aqui simula os dados onde o laço de repetição percorre.

foreach ($data as $v)
{
    echo '('.$v.') : '.implode('.',array_slice($arr, 0, 3)).PHP_EOL.'<br />';

    array_push($arr, array_shift($arr));
}
```

Vamos ver isso na prática, com cores:

```
    $arr = array('4285f4', '34a853', 'fbbc05', 'ea4335');
//$arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
$data = range(1, 100);

foreach ($data as $v)
{
    //echo '('.$v.') : '.implode('.',array_slice($arr, 0, 3)).PHP_EOL;
    for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++)
        echo '<div style="background-color:#'.$arr[$i].'; display:inline-block; padding:20px; margin:0px; border:0px;">########</div>';

    echo '<br />';
    array_push($arr, array_shift($arr));
}
```

[Veja um exmplo da saída do código - PHPfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/406m-7fu2)