# Numeros Aleatórios 0,9

Tags: php

Estou elaborando um teclado numérico, porém, ao imprimir a variável `num`, os números ficam repetidos, estou tentando deixá-los aleatório.

```
<?php
for($i=0; $i<=9; $i++){
    $num = rand(0,9)
?>
    <button class='btn btn-default' style='margin-top: 5px'><?php echo $num;?></button>         
<?php } ?>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Só um detalhe: você não quer gerar números aleatórios. Os números **sempre serão os mesmos**. O que você precisa é embaralhar os dados: `shuffle`.

Comment: Estou usando PHP @Maniero

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss exatamente isso mesmo

Comment: Será duplicada de: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/183927/5878, ou https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/31161/5878, ou https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/102405/5878

Comment: Com shuffle resolveu, obrigado.

Comment: Isso é o que chamamos de [pergunta camaleão](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=camaleao), pois você pergunta uma coisa e queria saber outra. Da forma que perguntou ficou explícito que queria gerar 10 números aleatórios sem repetição dentro do intervalo [0, 9]. Geraria o resultado esperado e a solução foi discutida nas perguntas linkadas pelo Maniero; a única coisa é que não é a forma mais simples de resolver.